# como puedo dar de alta categorías por medio de los Webservice de prestashop?

Tags: webservice, api, prestashop

estoy sincronizado una base de datos con el prestashop pero al momento de subir las categorías estas no se dan de alta  este es el template xml que tiene prestashop

```
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<category>
 <id/>
 <id_parent/>
  <active/>
 <id_shop_default/>
 <is_root_category/>
 <position/>
 <date_add/>
 <date_upd/>
 <name>
 <language id="1"/>
   <language id="2"/>
  </name>
  <link_rewrite>
  <language id="1"/>
  <language id="2"/>
   </link_rewrite>
    <description>
  <language id="1"/>
   <language id="2"/>
    </description>
    <meta_title>
   <language id="1"/>
    <language id="2"/>
    </meta_title>
    <meta_description>
    <language id="1"/>
    <language id="2"/>
    </meta_description>
    <meta_keywords>
   <language id="1"/>
   <language id="2"/>
   </meta_keywords>
   <associations>
   <categories>
   <category>
   <id/>
   </category>
   </categories>
   <products>
   <product>
   <id/>
   </product>
   </products>
   </associations>
   </category>
   </prestashop>
```

pero  no tiene un campo que me permita registrar los campos level_depth, nleft, nright de la tabla ps_category estos campos los necesito para que la categoría se muestre 
no se si conocen otra forma de hacerlo o como puedo llenar estos campos desde el webservices muchas gracias

Answer (score -1, accepted):

el xml debe  en la parte  debe de estar true a si
1

Comment: Esto es una respuesta? porque fue reportado como de muy baja calidad y no se que tiene que ver con la pregunta. Por favor mira [answer]. Si no lo mejoras, puede que te llenen de puntos negativos.